# File History - can it be used on a non-removable, non-OS partition?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, file-history

I'm thinking it would be nice to partition my C drive (SSD) and use the new drive letter for File History.

Is this possible?

Or will windows not allow using the new partition for File History because it exists on a non-removable drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Windows 10 File History drive](http://superuser.com/questions/1014814/change-windows-10-file-history-drive)

Comment: it's not a duplicate since the question I'm asking (internal vs external drive) isn't address there, however. That's a good link to have.

Comment: Given the fact you accepted Run5k's answer which outlines the exact same process as the process in the duplicate question your comment is confusing.

Comment: The question was not about how to change the File History drive, the question was if Windows will allow it in this scenario (the reason I asked instead of just trying it was that I would have to re-partition my boot drive first). The accepted answer answers this directly (but such info is not available on the link)

Comment: just create a folder where you want you file history to be (in a partition or in your C:). Enable sharing (right click, property) and the "network path" will appear (ex: \\ME-PC\windows File History). Copy it. Then Run "filehistory" / select drive / add network location / in  the field 'folder' past your network path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately the answer is "yes," you can do that.  As long as Windows perceives what you are utilizing as a different drive (in this case, your new partition), it should work.  It doesn't *need* to be a removable drive... for example, a network location will also work.

1. Right-click on **Start** and select **Control Panel**
2. Within the icons view, select **File History**
3. Click on **Select Drive**

   [image: Select Drive]
4. Within that interface, you can potentially select a local drive, choose a network drive by selecting **Show all network locations**, or manually navigate to a network share by selecting **Add a network location**

   [image: Add network location]

([Source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/55153-file-history-drive-select-windows-10-a.html))

When you have a few minutes to spare, this tutorial explains your potential options a bit more in-depth:

[How to Select a File History Drive in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/55153-file-history-drive-select-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: You should quote and cite the relevant information from your link.

Comment: I had every intention of doing so, good sir... typically, the real-world IT tasks need to take precedence over fine-tuning the Super User questions.

Comment: ( you can leave the answer not submitted until you complete it ) I do that all the time.

Comment: That is good advice, and I will definitely remember that for future reference.  I merely wanted to assure you that this wasn't a case of *neglect* on my part.  Nobody had actually answered this gentleman's question after more than two hours, so I wanted to help him out accordingly.